# AG-Grid React: How do you collected the sort order of a grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, ag-grid

How do you change the sort order of the columns and collect that info to save as user settings? 
 I was trying to use `onSortedChanged` but it is not working.

```js
const onSortChanged = (event: SortChangedEvent) => {
    console.log(
      'onSortChanged',
      event.columnApi.getColumnState().filter((s) => s.sort)
    );
  };
```

I followed the documentation on the AG-Grid website but it seems out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that if I call two different methods either will give me the current column state.

```js
const saveState = useCallback(() => 
     if (gridRef.current) {
        var value = gridRef.current.columnApi.getColumnState()
     }
}, []);
```

if you use these two built-in methods and call them on the grid this will give you the results I was looking for.

```js
onColumnResized = {saveState}
onColumnMoved = {saveState}
```